# Pushing data to (nested) array, depending on existing object field

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm pushing some data to an array within a forEach-loop:

```
let result = [];
data.forEach(function(part){
    let text = part.one + part.two;
    result.push({ 
        text: text, 
        element: [{ id: part._id, page: part.page }]
    });
});
```

But I need to check if `text` is already in any object of the array.

If there is such an object, then only the page `part.page` should be added to the array of this object with identical text field. 
Otherwise the data should just be added to the result array.

**Example**

```
result = [
    {
        text: 'Some text',
        element: [{ id: 1, page: '12-34'}]
    }
]
```

If the next `part`-elements would look like this:

```
{ id: 2, one: 'Some ', two: 'text', page: '45-67' }
{ id: 3, one: 'Another  ', two: 'text', page: '12-34' }
```

`result` should get

```
result = [
    {
        text: 'Some text',
        pages: [{ id: 1, page: '12-34'}, { id: 2, page: '45-67' }] // page added to the array, as text is identical
    },
    {
        text: 'Another text',
        pages: [{ id: 3, page: '12-34'}]
    }
]
```

**Additional question**

Is it possible to sort the result array first by the `text`-field and second the element-objects by the `page`-field?

This would be a wrong order for the first object:

```
[{ id: 2, page: '45-67'}, { id: 1, page: '12-34' }]
```

...and '**A**nother text' should be before '**S**ome text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to check if the element exists. In your case I would use `findIndex` for updating the nested array:

```
let index = result.findIndex(x => x.reference === reference);

if (index === -1) {
    result.push({ 
        text: text,
        element: [
            { 
                id: part._id, 
                page: part.page 
            }
        ]
    });
}
else {
    result[index].element.push(
        { 
            id: part._id, 
            page: part.page 
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use a lookup object like so:

```
result = [];
lut = {};
data.forEach(function(part){
    text = part.one + part.two;
    if (lut[text]){
        lut[text].element.push({ id: part._id, page: part.page });
    }else{
        lut[text]={ 
            text: text, 
            element: [{ id: part._id, page: part.page }]
        }
        result.push(lut[text]);
    }
});
```

when you're finished use the sort function on all the elements, it takes a comparator function as an argument where you can specify what you want to use for sorting

Comment: What about `result.filter(x=> x.text === text)` instead of a new object?

Comment: when you have a very large array and need to go through the entire thing for each new entry it can get very slow. using an object as a lookup is a lot faster because it doesnt have to scan the entire array but instead uses an intelligent lookup-mechanism